# What are the ways to make a validator script start to "live" on-chain?

Tags: validator

What are the scenarios in which a validator script will start to "live" on-chain? By "living" on-chain, I mean there is at least one UTxO sitting on the script address.

A trivial answer is anyone sending some ADA to the script address of the validator script will create an UTxO sitting on the script address.

Another possible solution is having a "parent" validator script that is designed in a way such that consuming it will lead to creation of an UTxO sitting on the script address of a "child" validator script.

I wonder if there are any other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Having an UTxO that a validator can spend doesn't activate the validator ( I suppose that's what you mean by "live" )

the validator only executes when trying to consume one of his UTxOs, but NOT when creating an UTxO.

So a validator only "lives" when spending (or minting, or staking), but in general is just a passive address.

You can think at validators as a person that makes the decision to sign a transaction based on a set of instructions (Plutus)

You as a person can receive ADA or Token without your need to allow the transaction; on the contrary, you as a person have to allow a transaction that uses one of your UTxOs by signing it, following your own logic

the same is true for validators, anyone can send ADA or tokens to them without any logic that allows that, but in order to spend a validator UTxO you need to run his logic, which makes him live

Comment: Yeah, you are absolutely right about script address being passive. My question wanted to know different ways to create an UTxO sitting at a given script address. There are already two ways that I have mentioned in the question. I just wanted to know any other possible ways to achieve it.

Comment: @Qin then what you are asking is for all possible ways to create an UTxO, and as the name "Unspent **Transaction Output**" implies, you need a transaction for that, no other ways

Comment: That is for sure that a transaction is needed. The two ways mentioned in the questions are two different types of transactions that can create an UTxO sitting at the script address. I was wondering if there were additional types of transactions other than the two mentioned in the question that can also create an UTxO sitting at the script address.